# What happened to my straight lines in 2.8?

Tags: mesh, geometry, bmesh

I modeled these letters in 2.7 no problem. I just brought them into 2.80 and the straight lines have this "back forth" look along the geometry.

The normals are all outside, I tried to re-do the sharpening (to 100%) and I can't figure out what else could be wrong.

[image: The backbone of the R]

[image]

[image]

I'm guessing it could be something about the new subsurf options, but increasing the quality doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Ok, putting the subsurf first mostly fixes the problems. Not sure why though.

Comment: See if this isn't related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128254/2-80-subdivision-surface-issues. Might be a bug.

Comment: The bug got fixed today, starting from tomorrow (24.01.2019) you should not see those artifacts any longer.